# SQL query select all rows of data which are duplicate only 

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to  have an SQL query to select all those rows which are duplicate. For example-in a column named OWNER_NAME, there are thousands of records. but I have to select only those names which are duplicate like

ajay
ajay singh
ajay sharma
bobby deol
bobby
vikram singh
vikram sharma.
means the whole alphabet series should be covered n all single names should be deleted

Comment: Can't see any duplicates there...?  Which of the above rows should be deleted?

Comment: Please put down an expected output out of the above inputs

Comment: are you saying you want to select single names which also appear as part of a full name, and delete those?

Comment: Suppose you have a record with a name of "devinda" but no records where that name is attached to a surname such as "Devinda Roy".  What happens then?  It's not a duplicate but it is a single name.  You need to be a lot clearer in your specifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would roughly do this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT owner_name,
          COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN instr(owner_name, ' ') = 0 then owner_name
                                           else substr(owner_name, 1, instr(owner_name, ' ') - 1)
                                       END) cnt
     FROM table
) WHERE cnt > 1
```

It will make groups according to the first word (until the first space if any). Maybe you want to `upper`ize it also.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to delete all rows consisiting only of the surname:

```
delete from my_tab where instr(name, ' ') = 0
```

This will delete all rows that do not contain a space character.

Comment: I think he said he wants to select them.

Comment: @Jobz - nope,the last senetence says "the whole alphabet series should be covered n all single names should be deleted"

Answer (score -1):

I would store this into a dataset and loop for duplicates.